# Freelance (billing issues)

Tags: taxes, freelance

I am an illustrator and graphic designer. Very recently, I have received an offer from an agency of illustrators. The agency has the main core in Europe and I live in the United States (under J2 visa with work permit). The question is:

To write valid invoices according to US laws, do I need some identification number as a company or something similar? or, on the other hand, is my (US) social security number enough?

Comment: *To write valid factures according to US laws* - I am not sure I understand what this means...

Comment: Well, in Spain you need a number, called "CIF" (until 2008) or "NIF" (after 2008, I think). 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_added_tax_identification_number

Comment: I think the problem is the word "facture" - this is an unusual English word and doesn't make sense in the context in which you've used it. [It means:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/facture) "The quality of the execution of a painting; an artist’s characteristic handling of the paint." Do you mean "invoice" instead?

Comment: I changed "facture" by "receipt/bill"

Comment: There is no special requirements for an "invoice" in the US... it's just another name for a bill--with an informal definition that it's usually more formal, and uniform. But there are no legal requirements.

Answer (score 2):

In order to write a valid [Invoice](http://www.vertex42.com/ExcelTemplates/excel-invoice-template.html) you don't need to have anything.  But if the company is going to hire you and pay you they may want to report the money they paid you on a [1099 form](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1099msc.pdf), for example, they will require a Tax Identification Number of some sort such as an [EIN](http://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Employer-ID-Numbers-EINs) or a Social Security Number, which you already have.

However, prior to you being able to obtain employment in any capacity as a [J-2 Visa Holder](http://j1visa.state.gov/basics/j2-visa/) you will need to get an employment authorization so not to violate the terms of your visa.

Comment: Does working as a contractor count as employment under that visa?

Comment: I already have work permit. The agency "represents" the artists. This means that the agency doesn't hire you. I don't know whow this facts affect to the 1099 form issue... Can you ellaborate a little bit more, please?

Comment: @Flimzy I think the issue is payment (see similar H4) question.  There is a "grey area" as explained by some immigration lawyers, and you will need one to explain it and set it up.  Given the ability of an OP of obtaining employment authorization I would suggest taking advantage of that option.

Comment: @guacho You have an employment authorization or a recruiter/agency that can help you find work?  These are by no means related to one another.

Comment: I have authorization to work in the US (at least, in the state of California). I also have an agency that help me to find work. I'm not sure about the meaning of "employment authorization". By the way, what does it mean "OP"?

Comment: @guacho OP = Original Poster = You in this case.  Employment Authorization is what you apply for if you want to work within the United States it normally isn't limited to a single state.  If you have one you should be able to get paid either individually or via you corporation if you choose to set one up.

Comment: @Karlson thankyou very much!